# Little numbers on city screen on Civ 2

Tags: civilization-2

I see a little green 1 on the resource map on my city screen on Civ 2 - what does it represent?

Pic with freehand circle very related.

[image]

P.S. I love how I have corruption with communism. :) I even have it in my capital! :-D I'm guessing it's a rounding error or something.

Comment: almost looks like a graphical bug. Is it always there...? or is this the first (and only) time you've seen it?

Comment: Do you have any mods?

Comment: @Wipqozn It's not on every city, and I have seen it before. I swear I knew what it was at one time by reading it on CivFanatics, but I can't find it anymore. @Edward nope. I wish I had the no-limit mod, as I've already conquered the world and am simply colonizing the whole thing. Gotta have somethign to keep me busy while I watch my daughter, and civ is perfect because it never requires pausing and colonization is so mindless :)

Comment: I think it may be possible that it has something to do with the top five cities, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Good question.  I mostly play the Test of Time version so I have no idea.

Comment: @Edward my top 5 are 27, 30, 27, 27, 23. The city in question is 25, so it is bigger than the lowest top-5, but there is a 29 as well that is not in top 5, so the city in question is not in the five largest cities.

Comment: @Wipqozn I just went through my cities (I have 109 at the moment...) and I find another green 1 in the same location on Nicodemia, a size 24 city.

Comment: Wow, this is an interesting one. I can't find anything in the manual. Maybe it is some sort of debugging output that got left in the game?

Comment: @Phydaux Yea, I can't find anything in the manual either. I even asked some of my friends who were apparent 'Civ 2 experts', and they couldn't tell me.

Comment: @Glowcoder Could we see a screenshot of the other city with a 1 in it's map?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number displayed on the Resource Map is a graphic glitch. There are 2 possible explanations, the later being the most likely since a different number is showing, for different people.

1.

As you can see in the image below, the numbers are only there, so the game knows where to place land and where to place water.

The image is taken from `C:\Civilization 2 - Test of Time\Original\Terrain2.bmp`

[image: Lower right corner indicates 1 is equal to land.]

Also the thread you spoke of in the comments to your question may be this one: [CivFanatics](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=125039)

2.

In the thread it is suggested that the number originates from

`C:\Civilization 2 - Test of Time\Original\Terrain4.bmp`

Where a number is placed on each River Mouth sprite.

[image: Water Mouths]